# How to extract word from text file to use as a variable?

Tags: python, regex, variables

I have a simple script that writes the network name to a log file. It displays the following.

```
All User Profile     : NET_NAME
```

what I would like to do is open that text file and extract just the `NET_NAME` part and then be able to use that as a variable and also save the text file with the changes.

I have tried using `split` function, it kind of works when using the text, but when trying to read from the file it doesn't work.  I have searched regex but do not know the syntax to achieve what I want.

Comment: is there any chance that the symbol `:` will occur somewhere else in the text other than just before `NET_NAME`?  
And is the space between the `:` and `NET_NAME` always there?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/2823755

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: @ Tacratis no the log file will just have that one line in the example with one instance of : and the space after :

Answer (score 0):

`split` can indeed be used to achieve this. In case you're using Python3 and the content is in `text.txt` file, the snippet below should be able to do the trick:

```
with open("text.txt", "rb") as f:
  content = f.read().decode("utf-8")
  name = content.split(":")[1].strip()

print(name)
```

Comment: @Taras that works and extracts NET_NAME and prints the output.  Is there anyway to write that to the file with out the other text? i try adding f.write(name) f.close. but i get error "line 18, in <module>
    f.write(name)
io.UnsupportedOperation: write"

Comment: @K.Meleo, you cannot and should not write into the file that is open as read-only (`r`). You should open a file for writing `open("output.txt", "w")` and use it instead of `f`.

Comment: @wwii, I prefer to be explicit about the encodings I expect to find in files :)